# Custom switch component with v-model doesn't work

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

trying to do my custom Switch component in VueJS following these manuals [Using v-model on Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components), [Adding v-model Support to Custom Vue.js Components](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/vuejs-add-v-model-support) but something wrong and it doesn't work.

My `SwitchTest` component:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" :id="_uid" 
          :value="value" 
          @input="updateData" 
          class="checkbox">
    <label :for="_uid" class="switch"></label>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["value"],
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  methods: {
    updateData($event) {
      console.log($event.target.value);
      this.$emit("input", $event.target.value);
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
.switch::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.checkbox:checked + .switch::after {
  left: 20px;
}
.checkbox:checked + .switch {
  background-color: #7983ff;
}
.checkbox {
  display: none;
}
</style>
```

And using `SwitchTest` component:

```html
    {{switch1}}
    <SwitchTest v-model="switch1"/>
    {{switch2}}
    <SwitchTest v-model="switch2"/>
```

You can see the whole MVCE example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-meninsky-zx7w0?file=/src/App.vue:32-131

When I toggle checkbox, its value doesn't change.
Where am I wrong?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkboxes are a special case where they have two states (checked / unchecked) which can be translated to two values. Normally, this is simply `true` / `false` but since you've bound a single `:value`, you'll only ever get the same value each time.

Try binding the Boolean `value` prop to `checked` and emit a `true` / `false` value

```html
<input
  type="checkbox"
  :checked="value"
  :id="_uid" 
  @input="$emit('input', $event.target.checked)" 
  class="checkbox"
>
```